# Access Redux Store in List of ReactElements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a list like this:

```
const form = [
    <Input title="What is your age?" onSubmit={} />, // this onSubmit sets age
    <MultipleChoice title="What is the weather today?" onSubmit={} />, // this onSubmit sets weather
    <Input title="What is the brand of your rain coat?" onSubmit={} /> // this onSubmit sets rainCoatBrand
]
```

NOTE: this list above is not defined inside of a React component. I also have a store like this:

```
age: number;
weather: string;
rainCoatBrand: string;
```

For each of the elements in `form`, how can I set the `onSubmit` method to update the store with the value I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [store.dispatch()](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) to achieve this from outside of a react component. Note that for this to work, you'd need [reducers](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers) defined somewhere in order to handle the dispatched actions and update the store accordingly.

```
import { store } from './storepath';

const form = [
    <Input 
       title="What is your age?" 
       onSubmit={() => store.dispatch({ // redux action payload })} 
    />, 
    <MultipleChoice 
       title="What is the weather today?" 
       onSubmit={() => store.dispatch({ // redux action payload })} 
    />
    <Input 
       title="What is the brand of your rain coat?" 
       onSubmit={() => store.dispatch({ // redux action payload })} 
    /> 

]
```

To get access to the actual value from the input, you'd need to modify the  input components themselves to handle this.

e.g.

```
export const MultipleChoice = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState();

   ...
   
   return <div title={props.title} onSubmit={() => props.onSubmit(value)}/>
}

const form = [
   <MultipleChoice 
       title="What is the weather today?" 
       onSubmit={(payload) => store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_WEATHER', payload })} 
    />,
    ...
]
```